# Get an ASP.NET control's auto generated name attribute?

Tags: asp.net, controls, attributes, webforms

I have a DropDownList and need to know its name in the code behind:

```
<select name="ctl00$cphMainContent$ddlTopic" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphMainContent$ddlTopic\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_cphMainContent_ddlTopic">
<option value="All">All</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the value "ctl00$cphMainContent$ddlTopic"

Is that possible?

Comment: Could you clarify 'Why' you want to do this?

Comment: Because we want to go "around" ASP.NET. Yes I know, bad idea but it's too late now, we have done it!

Comment: For clarity to wRaR's answer `myddl.ClientID` will give you the `id` attribute available in the generated HTML, and `myddl.UniqueID` will give you the `name` attribute that available in the generated HTML.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`myddl.ClientID` / `myddl.UniqueID`, depending on what you need, `name` or `id` attribute.

Comment: Just a note, ClientID/UniqueID are only available from PreRender onwards.